Least squared optimization with SciPy but without smoothing
I'm currently trying to unfold the neutron spectrum using Bonner spheres spectrometry (which is essentially an under-determined problem). I have been using least_squares from scipy.optimize but I'm getting the feeling that there's a smoothing step which is "flattening" my spectrum. The peaks are being broadened and I feel there is some sort of continuity conditions or smoothing steps that are being used to a achieve a somewhat less optimal results. Given that nature of the problem, there should be some narrow peaks (neutrons at a given energy value) for the number of counts/measurements to become accurate.
My function is the following:

def objective(spectrum, kernel, counts, energies):
    residual = np.matmul(kernel, spectrum) - counts
    return residual

def L2_regularization_alogrithm(alpha, beta, kernel, guess, counts, energies):

    guess_L2_reg = guess.reshape((len(guess),))
    counts_L2_reg = counts.reshape((len(counts),))
    used_kernel = kernel.copy()

    kernel_T = np.transpose(used_kernel)
    K = np.dot(kernel_T, used_kernel)
    LM = np.diag(np.diag(K))
    transfer = K + alpha * LM
    counts_L2_reg = np.matmul(kernel_T, counts_L2_reg)

    bounds = (0, np.inf)
    result = least_squares(objective, guess_L2_reg, args=(transfer, counts_L2_reg, energies), bounds=bounds)
    x = result.x
    return x.reshape((len(x), 1))

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this kind of problems ?
I tried different types of smoothing methods to reduce this effect, the only options were linear, soft_l1, huber, cauchy and arctan. This fucntion is giving the best results but still far from perfect. And I know that problem is solvable because I'm using a commercial software that's giving me very good results but I don't have access to its internal code. You can see the current result here:
Best result so far

We really need to see a graph of the raw data and also of a putative fit before it is possible to make any meaningful comments. If you know the psf of your experimental method than a matched filter is hard to beat for determining position and flux. Things can get tricky when peaks overlap in unhelpful ways (as with all deconvolution).

I've added my current best result.

Which one of those lines is the raw data? I presume you have (noisy?) spot flux values known along the logarithmic energy curve. And that you expect a peak at around 6MeV.
